# Выбор VPN реализации

Tags: vpn, маршрутизация

Добрый день.

Есть порядка десяти серверов. У каждого сервера может быть до 255 абонентов. И сервера объединены в общую сеть, но есть несколько, которые соединяются через один сервер. То есть один сервер видит другой только через третий. Вопрос защиты соединения не важен, её может и не быть совсем.

Мне необходимо создать сеть между абонентами и серверами, так, чтобы я мог с одного абонента пропинговать другого. Все ip адреса статические.

У меня была идея поднять vpn сеть на серверах, прописать серверам их соседей, и подключать каждого абонента к его серверу. Выбор пал на openvpn, там можно было на сервере прописать соседей, но адресация клиентов там не позволяет подключить 255 пользователей(там пары [1,2],[5,6]).

После этого выбрал l2tpd, там можно прописать серверу 255 абонентов(192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.3 и т.д.), но не могу найти подключение соседних серверов с их сеткой.

В идеале должно быть что один сервер имеет сеть 192.168.0.0/24, второй 192.168.1.0/24, третий 192.168.2.0/24 и т.д. Причём адресация в vpn не должна пересекаться с ip адресацией. Т.е. если я попробую с 192.168.0.1 пропинговать 192.168.1.2, то, если выберу интерфейс tun0(к примеру) то буду пинговать по vpn, а если выберу интерфейс eth0 то по обычной сети.

Есть ли готовая реализация такой идеи? Лучше если с открытым исходным кодом?

Comment: А вы это на какой ОС делаете. между серверами vpn не обязателен. Можно обойтись например ipip туннелем. Хотя сервера можно соединить любым способом, главное после этого явно прописать маршрутизацию на клиентские подсети через установленные туннели

Comment: @Mike
linux.
Получается,  для каждого сервера на каждом сервере необходимо  будет прописать маршрут? 
Я предполагал, что если использовать технологию vpn, то использовать её везде.
Есть ли возможность использовать что-то типа OSPF, чтобы маршруты сами перестраивались в случае потери связи?

Comment: Да, ставьте quagga, для нее туннели от любых других интерфейсов не отличаются, так что OSPF через них будет работать. Заодно она и все маршруты сама распространит по серверам и не надо будет писать их везде вручную. Правда если сами клиенты так же подключаются по vpn то таблицы маршрутизации будут большими. квагга скорее всего захочет распространять по сети путь до каждого клиента отдельно. Думаю этого можно избежать, но подсказать что то не смогу, с настройками OSPF не знаком.

Comment: @Mike Я не совсем понял как это будет работать и какой в итоге vpn выбрать?
Допустим я выбираю l2tp, а конкретно l2tpd, устанавливаю на один сервер(192.168.0.1). Цепляю к этому серверу абонентов(192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.3 и т.д.). То же самое делаю с вторым сервером(192.168.1.1) и аббонентами(192.168.1.3). Сервер видит сервер напрямую. Если я поставлю OSPF на все интерфейсы, то будет коллизия моей vpn сети с ip сетью. Если OSPF распространять только на vpn интерфейсы, то как сервера узнают друг о друге.

Comment: Если на это ещё накладывать ipip, то получается надо для каждого соединения серверов открывать тунель? Просто не особо понимаю как эта связка будет работать

Comment: Не совсем понимаю. "Сервер видит напрямую" - т.е. у вас на одном сервере на сетевухе скажем 192.168.0.1 и на втором сервере, включенном в эту физическую сеть скажем 192.168.0.254. Если клиенты в самой физической сети, то vpn им не нужен - пусть работают напрямую. Но если они на vpn, то им может не надо давать адреса из той же подсети. выделите их отдельно. Хотя в принципе и такая конфигурация возможна, вы называете это коллизией - но ее тут нет. главное что бы в физической сети и vpn не оказалось двух одинаковых ip. И еще надо тогда включать proxy arp на интерфейсе

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42695/discussion-between-kostap-and-mike).